# Remove Nth Node From End of List Runtime Error

Tags: runtime-error

Given linked list: 1->2->3->4->5, and n = 2.

After removing the second node from the end, the linked list becomes 1->2->3->5.
        Hi, I could run my code in my computer however the leetcode always says `Runtime Error`. Am I doing something wrong in memory? I ran the same case which leetcode said I was wrong. 
    I believe I checked all the corner cases.
    input [1,2] output [2]

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        if(!head) return head;
        ListNode* tmp =head;
        int size =1;
        while(tmp->next){
          tmp=tmp->next;
          size++;
        } 
        if(n>size) return head;
        ListNode* prev = head;
        //delete the head
        if (n==size){
            if(prev->next){
            prev=prev->next;
            delete head;
            head = prev;
            return head;
            } else {
                delete head;
                return NULL;
                 }
        }else {
        for (int j=0; j<size-n-1; j++) {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        tmp=prev->next;
        //if tail, delete, else reconnect.
        if (tmp->next){
        prev->next = tmp->next;
        }
        delete tmp;
        return head;
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: You missed a corner case. Keep debugging.

Comment: I believe I checked all the corner cases. 1: empty list 2: only 1 slot and n==1   3: more than 1 slot and n=0 4: more than 1 slot and n>0. I could successfully run all the same cases from leetcode in my complier

Comment: Try "list with 2 elements, n==1".

Comment: Let try [1,2], n==1, so we want delete[2], and the out put should be [1], you see here 'prev==head', and size==2; then it won't be in the loop because j=0; j<0 contradicts, and prev->next exists, then we have tmp=prev->next and tmp->val==2, finally we delete tmp and return a head with [1], I ran this successfully in my complier

Comment: I solved the problem, that was not because the corner cases. Maybe cause the empty list will be initialed. just delete "if (tmp->next)" Thanks!

Comment: That was the corner case: When deleting the last element in a list with more than one element.